# How to set and access an environment variable in GitHub Actions?

Tags: react-native, automation, expo, devops, github-actions

I am in the process of automating my `react-native` ***Expo*** release-cycle. I am using `release channels` in Expo to build `staging` and `production` builds. For example, on every push to `staging-v1` GitHub branch, the action below is triggered.

```yaml
//staging.yaml

name: Release to staging
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - staging*
jobs:
  publish:
    name: Install and publish on staging channel
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 12.x
      - uses: expo/expo-github-action@v5
        with:
          expo-version: 3.x
          expo-username: ${{ secrets.EXPO_CLI_USERNAME }}
          expo-password: ${{ secrets.EXPO_CLI_PASSWORD }}
          expo-packager: npm
      - run: npm install
      - run: expo publish --release-channel ${{ GITHUB_REF }}
```

`{{ GITHUB_REF }}` holds the current branch name. So when I push my changes to `staging-v1` this action runs. However, I am getting this error.

[image: github-actions-error]

I've tried setting `env` variables, it did not work also. I just want to append my `branch_name` to the `expo publish` command. Ultimately, when building, the `run` command should look like this.

```
 - run: npm install
 - run: expo publish --release-channel staging-v1
```

Any insight into this problem will be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: The title "How to set and access a Workflow variable in GitHub Actions?" of this question is way too general. The answer only concerns specific values; it is not about reading and writing arbitrary variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I've found the solution. I used the [github-slug-action workflow](https://github.com/rlespinasse/github-slug-action) to access my `branch_name`.

```yaml
name: Release to staging
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - staging*
jobs:
  publish:
    name: Install and publish on staging channel
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 12.x
      - uses: expo/expo-github-action@v5
        with:
          expo-version: 3.x
          expo-username: ${{ secrets.EXPO_CLI_USERNAME }}
          expo-password: ${{ secrets.EXPO_CLI_PASSWORD }}
          expo-packager: npm
      - run: npm install
      - name: Run tests
        run: |
          npm test
      - uses: rlespinasse/github-slug-action@v2.x
      - run: expo publish --release-channel=${{ env.GITHUB_REF_SLUG }}
```

Here is the log.

[image: github-actions-log]

Answer (score 3):

I built a GitHub Action for this: [FranzDiebold/github-env-vars-action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-environment-variables-action)

The usage is as follows:

```
steps:
  - uses: FranzDiebold/github-env-vars-action@v1.2.0
  - name: Print environment variables
    run: |
      echo "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_SLUG=$GITHUB_REPOSITORY_SLUG"
      echo "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER=$GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER"
      echo "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER_SLUG=$GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER_SLUG"
      echo "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_NAME=$GITHUB_REPOSITORY_NAME"
      echo "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_NAME_SLUG=$GITHUB_REPOSITORY_NAME_SLUG"
      echo "GITHUB_REF_SLUG=$GITHUB_REF_SLUG"
      echo "GITHUB_REF_NAME=$GITHUB_REF_NAME"
      echo "GITHUB_REF_NAME_SLUG=$GITHUB_REF_NAME_SLUG"
      echo "GITHUB_SHA_SHORT=$GITHUB_SHA_SHORT"
```

An example output is:

```
GITHUB_REPOSITORY_SLUG=ajinkabeer-test-repo
GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER=ajinkabeer
GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER_SLUG=ajinkabeer
GITHUB_REPOSITORY_NAME=test-repo
GITHUB_REPOSITORY_NAME_SLUG=test-repo
GITHUB_REF_SLUG=refs-heads-staging-v1
GITHUB_REF_NAME=staging-v1
GITHUB_REF_NAME_SLUG=staging-v1
GITHUB_SHA_SHORT=e2e4f0ab
```

A demo for all Operating systems (Linux, macOS and Windows) is also available in the [demo workflows file of the repository](https://github.com/FranzDiebold/github-env-vars-action/blob/primary/.github/workflows/demo.yml)!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It looks good, I am definitely going to try this one out. Thanks again :)